# Converting a hex-string representation to actual bytes in Python

Tags: python, hex, representation

i need to load the third column of this text file as a hex string

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/skia/emoji/gmojiraw.txt

```
>>> open('gmojiraw.txt').read().split('\n')[0].split('\t')[2]
'\\xF3\\xBE\\x80\\x80'
```

how do i open the file so that i can get the third column as hex string:

```
'\xF3\xBE\x80\x80'
```

i also tried binary mode and hex mode, with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can:

1. Remove the `\x`-es
2. Use .decode('hex') on the resulting string

Code:

```
>>> '\\xF3\\xBE\\x80\\x80'.replace('\\x', '').decode('hex')
'\xf3\xbe\x80\x80'
```

Note the appropriate interpretation of backslashes. When the string representation is '\xf3' it means it's a single-byte string with the byte value 0xF3. When it's '\\xf3', which is your input, it means a string consisting of 4 characters: `\`, `x`, `f` and `3`

Comment: wow, thanks that worked, stackoverflow is not allowing me to accept that as an answer right now!

Comment: @kevin: I'm not sure why that would be, but don't hurry. People may come up with better answers than this. You can always accept it later (i.e. in a couple of days)

Comment: it said, i have to wait atleast 10 mins before accepting answer. ok, i will wait to accept the answer! but i doubt if any other answer can better this

Comment: decode('hex') doesn't work for Python3, but if you need a Python2 answer this is a good one

Answer (score 7):

#### Quick'n'dirty reply

```
your_string.decode('string_escape')

>>> a='\\xF3\\xBE\\x80\\x80'
>>> a.decode('string_escape')
'\xf3\xbe\x80\x80'
>>> len(_)
4
```

#### Bonus info

```
>>> u='\uDBB8\uDC03'
>>> u.decode('unicode_escape')
```

#### Some trivia

What's interesting, is that I have Python 2.6.4 on Karmic Koala Ubuntu (`sys.maxunicode==1114111`) and Python 2.6.5 on Gentoo (`sys.maxunicode==65535`); on Ubuntu, the unicode_escape-decode result is `\uDBB8\uDC03` and on Gentoo it's `u'\U000fe003'`, both correctly of length 2. Unless it's something fixed between 2.6.4 and 2.6.5, I'm impressed the 2-byte-per-unicode-character Gentoo version reports the correct character.

Comment: The `\Uxxxxxxxx` vs `\uxxxx\uxxxx` appears to be a build-time option introduced in Python 2.6. In "narrow builds" code points outside the BMP are represented as UTF-16 surrogate pairs. See tangentially [issue #1477](http://bugs.python.org/issue1477).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python2.6+ here is a safe way to use eval

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> item='\\xF3\\xBE\\x80\\x80'
>>> literal_eval("'%s'"%item)
'\xf3\xbe\x80\x80'
```

Comment: +1: For Python 3 support, plus I like how this also works if not all of the bytes are escaped, for example it will convert 'hello\\x00world' just fine.

Answer (score 1):

After stripping out the "\x" as Eli's answer, you can just do:

```
int("F3BE8080",16)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the source, you can use `eval('"%s"' % data)`