# python string to hex with escaped hex values

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a string like "Some characters \x00\x80\x34 and then some other characters". How can I convert the regular characters to their hex equivalent, while converting \x00 to the actual 00 hex value?
binascii.hexlify() considers '\', 'x', '0', '0' as actual characters.

Later edit:
The string itself is produced by another function. When I print it, it actually prints "\x00".

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519125/converting-a-hex-string-representation-to-actual-bytes-in-python

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding you are trying to convert only the characters that are not hex values to hex. It would help if you gave a sample input string that you are trying to convert to hex.

Also you can convert to hex values using just the built in encoding and decoding method. That should take care of what you are trying to do. The following three lines are what I ran in terminal of my machine, and gave the output you are expecting. I also attached an image to show you. Hope it helps:

```
aStr = "Some characters \x00\x80\x34 and then some other characters"
aStr.encode("hex")
aStr.encode("hex").decode("hex")
```

[image: Here is the code I ran in my terminal.]

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking, since `binascii.hexlify` should work:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = "\x00\x80\x34"
>>> binascii.hexlify(s)
'008034'
>>> s = "foobar \x00\x80\x34 foobar"
>>> binascii.hexlify(s)
'666f6f6261722000803420666f6f626172'
```

> foorbar = `666f6f6261722`, space = `20`

↳ https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html